# addEventListener fires on page load when trying to use prompt

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-objects

I can't get the `addEventListener` to only fire when clicked, instead of page load.

I tried looking for an answer for `addEventListener` for prompt but only found answers for alert and tried them but nothing works.

```
const poll = {
        question: 'What is your favorite programming language?',
        options: [ '0: JavaScript', '1: PHP', '2: Rust', '3: C++' ],
        registerNewAnswer:
            Number( prompt( 'What is your favourite programming language?\n' +
                '     0: JavaScript\n' +
                '     1: PHP\n' +
                '     2: Rust\n' +
                '     3: C++' ) ),
        answerPoll() {
            switch ( this.registerNewAnswer ) {
                case 0:
                    this.answers[ 0 ]++;
                    console.log( this.answers, 'Vote for JavaScript' );
                    break;

                case 1:
                    this.answers[ 1 ]++;
                    console.log( this.answers, 'Vote for PHP' );
                    break;

                case 2:
                    this.answers[ 2 ]++;
                    console.log( this.answers, 'Vote for Rust' );
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.answers[ 3 ]++;
                    console.log( this.answers, 'Vote for C++' );
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log( 'Not a Choice on the List Try Again!' );
            }

        },
        answers: new Array( 4 ).fill( 0 )
    };
   

    document.querySelector( '.poll' ).addEventListener( 'click',
        poll.answerPoll.bind( poll ) );
```

Comment: and there is no error message in the console?

Comment: none, I even tried using a debugger.

Comment: this is the entire code is in your html header ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `registerNewAnswer` is a property, and it's trying to compute that property by prompting for your favourite programming language. If your goal is for that prompt to only happen when `answerPoll()` gets called, `registerNewAnswer` needs to be a method called by `answerPoll()`.

```js
const poll = {
        question: 'What is your favorite programming language?',
        options: [ '0: JavaScript', '1: PHP', '2: Rust', '3: C++' ],

        registerNewAnswer() { /* <—- you made this a property instead of a method */

            return Number( prompt( 'What is your favourite programming language?\n' +
                '     0: JavaScript\n' +
                '     1: PHP\n' +
                '     2: Rust\n' +
                '     3: C++' ) )
        },
        answerPoll() {

            switch ( this.registerNewAnswer() /* <—- you weren't calling the registerNewAnswer method */  ) {

                // ...
            }
        },
        answers: new Array( 4 ).fill( 0 )
    };
```